# javascript callback context issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Trying to make a simple widget.
Steps:

1) Load jQuery if not already there
2) Callback a function

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load(callback){
        console.log('load');
        if (typeof jQuery !== "function") {
            var js = document.createElement("script");
            var he = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            js.type = "text/javascript";
            js.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js";
            he.appendChild(js);
            js.addEventListener("load", function () {
                callback();
            });
        }
        else
            {
                callback();
            }
    }


    load(function(){
        chart();
    })


    function chart(){
        $('#chart').html("id : "+Math.random());
    }

    // alert('This alert breaks!');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code works without alert. Cant understand the context issue

Thanks

Comment: Works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/Zwa7Q/

Comment: Just you are not waiting for DOM to be ready so `$('#chart')` could be empty object

Comment: @A.Wolff Cant thank you enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, figured out the problem.

Your code is not inside a DOM ready handler.

It will work if the alert isnt there since the function call is asynchronous and the DOM is ready before the AJAX is complete.

**but** when the alert is there, it create a breakpoint in your code and the DOM will not complete until you click *ok*. The probleme is that the AJAX request isnt stopped. When you click *ok*, the AJAX will be finish and run the callback before the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Move your script block out of the `head` tag and place it at the end of the `body` right before `</body>`.